# How I can calculate this integral

Tags: integration, derivatives, exponential-function, partial-derivative, distribution-theory

The integral is the following and I want to produce it in terms of $r$.  Is there a theory that the partial producer enters the integral?

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial r}  \int_{F^{-1}(p)}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\overline{F}(x)}{1-p} \right)^r dx,\quad\overline{F}(x)=e^{-(\lambda x)^\alpha}$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule?wprov=sfti1

Comment: Why the tag 'distribution-theory'?

Comment: because of my equation depends from destributio theory!